# cell is what percent of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a total number of let's say 12,504 (my whole number).
I have numbers in a few different categories that will total up to that whole number. for example BL1 = 144 (which I know is 1.5%) & BL2 = 1296. I need a formula that will tell me what % BL1, BL2 ect. is of 12,504.
I need to be able to paste this formula to many workbooks.

Thank you!

Comment: `BL1/12504` and format as percentage?

Comment: not understanding your response. I need a formula that will compute that 144 is 1.5% of 12,504, instead of figuring out the % manually for 100 of these similar scenarios.

Comment: I'm assuming `BL1`s the cell with 144 in it and suggested a formula accordingly. You can then copy it and populate down the appropriate column

Comment: yes, you should reference whatever cell contains 12,504

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula:

```
=B1/$A$1
```

[image]